# Is there a bug with SSMS 18.4 when you script column level permissions?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms

I'm running SSMS 18.4 against SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.

I was using the GUI editor to set up column level permissions on a table and then scripted my changes to a new query window to execute the permission changes.  After I executed the generated SQL I refreshed and opened the properties window of the user group in question and noticed that not all of the columns where selected for access in the available list of columns for the table.  I went back and reviewed the code and SSMS inserted an errant REVOKE statement in the middle of the list of columns that I was granting permissions to.  I've replicated the issue only a few times.  It seems  inconsistent so I'm checking in with the community to make sure it isn't something I'm doing.  I've only see this when working with column level permissions.

Steps I completed to get undesired behavior.

Database>Security>User Group>Properties

Highlight Object Name (table or view).

Check Grant for SELECT Permission.

Click Column Permissions button.

Check GRANT boxes for specific columns and hit OK.

Script Action to New Query Window.

Resulting SQL that interrupts some of the columns from setting expected permissions.  Or the entire object if SSMS places the REVOKE at the end of all the GRANT statements.

```
use [Database]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.[Table] ([Column1]) TO [User Group] 
GO

use [Database]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.[Table] ([Column2]) TO [User Group] 
GO
use [Database]
GO
REVOKE SELECT ON Schema.[Table] TO [User Group] 
GO
use [Database]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.[Table] ([Column3]) TO [User Group] 
GO
use [Database]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.[Table] ([Column4]) TO [User Group] 
GO
use [Database]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.[Table] ([Column5]) TO [User Group] 
GO
```

As you can see, the REVOKE in the middle would only grant SELECT permissions on the last three columns and not the first two.

Comment: Stack Overflow would be the wrong place to report said bugs, if it is one. Personally, however, I prefer to always run the commands myself anyway and not trust the GUI. The whole statement could be simplfied to `GRANT SELECT ON [Schema].[Table] (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5) TO [User Group];`

Comment: Thanks for the simplification tip!  I know that SO isn't the place to submit bugs...I just wanted to check in with people first before I actually submit the bug to MSFT.
I only use the GUI to cut down on writing so much SQL by hand for permission stuff.  It would become tedious on some of our tables that have 50-100 columns.  Not my design btw...